# How Can I Use File.Create Web Path as Parameter at .Net Core

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, file-upload

Version .NetCore 2.1
There is a share path on IIS like h ttps://foo.com/bar"
this bar folder on IIS my web site

http-s://mysite.com/bar/request returns status code 200

if targetFilePath is "z:\myfiles\cookieRecipe.txt" this code will success.

But if targetFilePath is **"http-s://mysite.com/bar/cookieRecipe.txt"** this throw an excepiton like "System.IO.IOException","HResult":-2147024773,"Message":"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect *Z:\Publish\MyWeb.Web\http-s:\mysite.com\bar"* **why this code added Z:\Publish\MyWeb.Web to my path? how can I solve this?**

```
  using (var targetStream = File.Create(targetFilePath))
  {
     await item.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
  }
```

Comment: 1) "http-s://mysite.com/bar/cookieRecipe.txt" is an invalid path. 2) .NET Core tried to compute another path based on your invalid input (adding a base path), which  became another invalid path and caused another failure. How to solve that? Serve a valid file path.

Comment: that is the physical path .you need virtual path, which is in asp.net mappath. collect it from private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _env;

        public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment)
        {
            _env = env;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content(_env.ApplicationBasePath);
        }

Comment: retrieve ApplicationBasePath

Answer (score 0):

The document has explained that only relative or absolute **path** get supported by file.open(path).Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netcore-3.1

If you want to read something from remote, then please use webclient instead.

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Stream stream = client.OpenRead("https://mysite/a");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```